# Rails: DISTINCT for use with "MyModelClass.where(..."

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, select, distinct

I know you can do `MyModelClass.select("DISTINCT name")` in Rails.

Is `DISTINCT` also available for use with `MyModelClass.where(:name => 'me')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this:
MyModelClass.where(name: "me").uniq

Generated sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `my_tbl`.* FROM `my_tbl` WHERE `my_tbl`.`name` = 'xyz'
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the query actually gets the `DISTINCT` keyword rather than the resulting array being minimised.

Answer (score 5):

yes, you can just chain those calls.

```
MyModelClass.where(name: 'me').select('DISTINCT name')
```

Or, [even better](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

```
MyModelClass.where(name: 'me').uniq.pluck(:name)
```